# Show that : $ \sup_n\mathbb E (|X_n|)<\infty\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\mathbb{P}(\{|X_n|>n\})} $

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of random variable, such that:
$$
\dfrac{M_j}{2}<\int_{j-1<|X_n|\leq j}{|X_{n}(t)|d\mathbb{P}(t)}\leq M_j+\dfrac{1}{j^2} \qquad\forall n\geq 1 \text{ et }1\leq j\leq n^2
$$
with $M_j>0$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{M_j}<\infty$.

Show that :
$$
\sup_n\mathbb E (|X_n|)<\infty\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\mathbb{P}(\{|X_n|>n\})}<\infty
$$
An idea please.

Comment: I corrected it, thank you

Comment: Still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your last implication has still no sense.

Comment: I did not understand why. Where is the fault?

Comment: shouldn't there be $\sup \mathbb E[|X_n|] < \infty$ and in the sum $\mathbb P(|X_n| > n^2)$ ?

Comment: For $"\sup_n\mathbb E (|X_n|)"$ you are right I corrected it and thank you, but for $"\mathbb{P}(\{|X_n|>n^2)"$ what I wrote is true.

Comment: Is this "et" french?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mathbb E[|X_n| \chi_{(|X_n| \le n^2)}] \le\sum_{j=1}^\infty M_j + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2}$. Let $M = \sum_{j=1}^\infty M_j$ and $L = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j^2}$ (in fact $L = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$, but we only need that it is finite). By assumption $M< \infty$, too. so that $\underset{n}{\sup}\{ \mathbb E[|X_n| \chi_{(|X_n| \le n^2)}]\}$ is finite.

We have $\mathbb E[|X_n|] = \mathbb E[|X_n| \chi_{( |X_n| \le n^2)}] + \mathbb E[|X_n| \chi_{(|X_n| > n^2)}]$. With assumption that $\sup \mathbb E[|X_n|]$ is finite, we see that means $\sup \mathbb E[|X_n| \chi_{ (|X_n| > n^2 )}] = K< \infty$. Since $\mathbb E [|X_n| \chi_{( |X_n| > n^2)} ] \ge \mathbb E[n^2 \chi_{(|X_n| > n^2)}] = n^2 \mathbb P(|X_n| > n^2)$, we see that also $\sup n^2 \mathbb P(|X_n| > n^2) \le K$. In particular, for all $n \in \mathbb N$ we have $\mathbb P(|X_n| > n^2) \le \frac{K}{n^2}$ which is summable.

Moreover, looking for $k \in \{0,1,...,n^2-n-1\}$ at $(n+k) \mathbb P(|X_n| \in [n+k,n+k+1]) \le \mathbb E[|X_n| \chi_{(|X_n| \in [n+k,n+k+1])} \le M_{n+k} + \frac{1}{(n+k)^2}$, we see that $$ \mathbb P(|X_n| \in [n,n^2]) \le \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-n-1} \frac{M_{n+k}}{n+k} + \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-n-1} \frac{1}{(n+k)^3} $$

Now, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|X_n| > n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|X_n| \in [n,n^2]) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(|X_n| \ge n^2)$. We know the second one is finite. Moreover $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{n^2} \frac{1}{(n+k)^3} \le \sum_{n=2}^\infty \int_{n-1}^{n^2} \frac{1}{x^3} dx \le \sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(n-1)^2} < \infty$. (Note that we've actually add lot of terms in the sum and in integral, but that wasn't crucial). So all that left is to check whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-n-1} \frac{M_{n+k}}{n+k}$ is finite. But we know that $M_{n+k} \le 2\mathbb E[|X_{n+k}| \chi_{(|X_{n+k}| \in [n+k,n+k+1])}] = 2f(n+k)$. Since both $f(n+k)$ and $n+k$ are positive, we can sum in whatever order we like. And what order we like? We would like to sum with respect to $m= n+k$. For given $m =n+k$ there are at most $2m$ pairs $(n,k)$ such that $n+k =m$ (in fact there is much less than them, but no problem). So we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-n-1} \frac{M_{n+k}}{n+k} \le \sum_{m=1}^\infty 2m \frac{2f(m)}{m} = 4\sum_{m=1}^\infty f(m) = 4 \sum_{m=1}^\infty \mathbb E[|X_m| \chi_{(|X_m| \in [m, m+1]}] \le 4 \sum_{m=1}^\infty M_m + \frac{1}{m^2}$.

What we know about the last one is that it is finite.

Comment: you can explain to me why we have: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-n-1} \frac{M_{n+k}}{n+k} \le \sum_{m=1}^\infty 2m \frac{2f(m)}{m} $

Comment: in other words, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^{n^2-n-1}$ means to sum over all pairs $(k,n)$ such that $k \in \{0,1,...,n^2-n-1\}$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. Since our terms are positive, we can add more of them, so lets sum just over every pair $(n,k)$ such that $k \in \mathbb N$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. In what manner we want to sum over those pairs? By looking at the sum of it's components. How many pairs such that $m = n+k$ are? You don't need to count explicitly, it is enough to show there are less than for example $2m$ such pairs. So we need to add $\frac{M_{n+k}}{n+k}$ less than $2(n+k)$times

Comment: And when $m = n+k$ is fixed, this means that for every $m \in \mathbb N$ we have at most (clearly less) $2m$ pairs $(n,k)$ such that $m=n+k$, so we are adding (again at most) $2m$ terms $\frac{M_m}{m}$, hence our inequality